# IntelliJ IDEA having problem with Kotlin Gradle dependency

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

So, I'm rewriting some of my projects from Java to Kotlin, because I'm overall more comfortable with the language and I stumbled upon a little problem with my IDE (InteliJ IDEA Ultimate).

I published one of my libraries to public repo on [GitHub](https://github.com/ThePlay3r/PLJRApi-Spigot) and used it as an dependency in other project using **Gradle** and **JitPack**, it downloads and is included in *"External Libraries"*.

However I'm unable to use any of it in my **.kt** files. (IDE shows *"Unresolved Reference"* error.)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFDWN.png

This does not happen, when I'm trying to do the same thing in Java. (Same project) https://i.stack.imgur.com/NV22F.png

---

**build.gradle.kts**

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = "papermc-repo"
        url = uri("https://papermc.io/repo/repository/maven-public/")
    }
    maven { 
        name = "jitpack"
        url = uri("https://www.jitpack.io") 
    }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit"))

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    compileOnly("com.destroystokyo.paper:paper-api:1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT")
    implementation("com.github.ThePlay3r:PLJRApi-Spigot:563362408c")
}
```

---

It's quite frustrating as I was really excited about Kotlin, but this makes me unable to do much.
Does anyone have any idea how to *fix* this, or any *alternative* for adding libraries to my project?

Comment: I've seen similar issues before. Check and see that both projects were compiled with the same Java version.

Also note: you don't _have_ to use Kotlin Gradle (`build.gradle.kts`) for Kotlin-enabled projects; normal Gradle (`build.gradle`) will also suffice once you add the Kotlin plugin at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's an known issue, that was reported and is tracked here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25709.

My current, temporary fix is excluding some of the kotlin's files in the `shadowJar` task.

```
tasks.named<ShadowJar>("shadowJar") {
    exclude("**/*.kotlin_metadata")
    exclude("**/*.kotlin_module")
    exclude("**/*.kotlin_builtins")
}
```